# Consider the Vector space $V$ of real polynomial of degree less than or equall to $n$. Fix distinct real numbers $\{|p(a_j)|:0\le j\le k\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

(CSIR-UGC NET, Mathematical Sciences, June 2017)

> Consider the Vector space $V$ of real polynomial of degree  less than
>   or equall to $n$. Fix distinct real numbers $a_0, a_1,..., a_k$. For
>   $p \in V$   $$\max\{|p(a_j)|:0\le j\le k \}$$ define norm on $V$
>
> (1)only if $k<n$.
>
> (2)only if $k\ge n.$
>
> (3)if $k+1\le n$.
>
> (4) if $k+1\ge n.$

(Axiom 1(Positivity))$$\|p\|=\max\{|p(a_j)|:0\le j\le k \}\ge |p(a_j)|_{0\le j\le k }\ge0.$$
$$\|p\|=\max\{|p(a_j)|:0\le j\le k \}=0 \iff|p(a_j)|_{0\le j\le k }=0. $$
If $k>n$, which contradict the fundamental theorem of algebra. So, $p=0$.

(Axiom 2(Scalar Multiplication)) Easy to verify.

(Axiom 3(triangle inequality)) Easy to verify.

I got option 4. Am I right? I have a doubt about the proof of Axiom 1. Please verify my solution. Can you help me?

Comment: I think your notation might be off a little bit: the function is totally ill-defined if $k>n$ (do you see why?). Once you sort that out, the main issue to be concerned about is, as you noticed, whether the polynomial vanishing at all the points you checked implies it is identically zero. The fundamental theorem of algebra tells you that this happens if you check *more* than $d$ points, if $d$ is the degree.

Comment: @Ian Can you help me, How it is ill-defined?May I know how my notations are off?

Comment: I think you want the points to be $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_k$ (the last index being $k$, not $n$). As it stands $k>n$ makes no sense because there is no $a_{n+1}$ to evaluate at.

Comment: Thank you for pointing my mistake.:) @Ian

Comment: @Ian What about my solution. Am I correct?

Comment: Your positivity argument is right. Scalar multiplication is indeed quite trivial. Be careful when checking the triangle inequality (you probably have it right, but still).

Comment: @Ian Thank you very much.

Comment: @nmasanta This question is older.

Comment: I know but it has no answer. The link that support my claim has already accepted answer.